# Terraform S3 Sever access logs keeps generating with no action made

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I was creating a Terraform project that should create 3 buckets (1 public,1 private, 1 for server access logs)

Main.tf

```
module "public-s3" {
  source        = "./modules"
  name          = "public"
  acl           = "public-read"
  target_bucket = module.logging-s3.bucket-name

  depends_on = [module.logging-s3]
}

module "private-s3" {
  source        = "./modules"
  name          = "private"
  acl           = "private"
  target_bucket = module.logging-s3.bucket-name

  depends_on = [module.logging-s3]
}

module "logging-s3" {
  source = "./modules/logging"
  name   = "logging"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"

}
```

./Module/s3.tf

```
resource "random_integer" "bucket-int" {
  min = 1000000
  max = 5000000
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "${var.name}-${random_integer.bucket-int.result}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

  block_public_acls       = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  block_public_policy     = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  ignore_public_acls      = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  restrict_public_buckets = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "bucket-acl" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.ownership,
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.public
  ]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  acl    = var.acl
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "logs-delivery" {
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  target_bucket = var.target_bucket
  target_prefix = "log-${var.name}/"

  depends_on = [var.target_bucket]

}

output "bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3.bucket
}
```

./Module/logging/logging-s3.tf

```
resource "random_integer" "bucket-int" {
  min = 1000000
  max = 5000000
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "${var.name}-${random_integer.bucket-int.result}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

  block_public_acls       = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  block_public_policy     = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  ignore_public_acls      = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
  restrict_public_buckets = var.acl == "public-read" ? false : true
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "bucket-acl" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.ownership,
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.public
  ]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  acl    = var.acl
}


output "bucket-name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3.bucket
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_write_logs" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  policy = <<EOF
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-1684330819963",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1684330819758",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.s3.bucket}/*"
        }
    ]
}
  EOF
}
```

everything works perfectly fine! logs are coming as intended, however, even though I am not making any additional action, logs are keep coming (under the name of my IAM user) and as well terraform is assuming my role to make more actions even though I am not making any Terraform action, must mention that I am using SSO (so the role from my end is assumed too)

A good solution is creating life cycle for the files to avoid high costs, however, I want to understand why these logs are keep generating without any action made from my end?

can I somehow limit the API calls that are logged?

P.S
I am pretty new to Terraform so have mercy on me if I made bad code styling or non efficient solutions, this is my first coding project ever

- I was trying to close VSCode to make sure session is closed with Bash
- I was searching on StackOverFlow and other resources for similar issues and couldn't find any evidence or explanation

Comment: What log entries are you seeing? What actions are occurring?

Comment: REST.GET.BUCKET - "GET /private-2230255?list-type=2&encoding-type=url&max-keys=1000&fetch-owner=true&delimiter=%2F&prefix= HTTP/1.1" 200 - 306 - 32 30 "-" "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.1030 Linux/5.4.241-160.348.amzn2int.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.362-b10 java/1.8.0_362 vendor/Oracle_Corporation cfg/retry-mode/standard" - +2MZpOWXm499v0cB9NsiNgpfpLmNaFRj3hOe3v0vO4pnrbWHW/QmV7AsdpB3EuG243QVZZszbcw= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader s3.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2 - -

Comment: Do you have the S3 bucket(s) open in the AWS console in your browser?

Comment: The only bucket in the console that is open infront of me was the logging bucket... as well i turned off everything and went outside at the time of this log... however... me checking today... i see just few more... not as intensive as yesterday (which was the day of deployment)

Comment: I would check for any other browser tabs, because that example log you've posted is from the S3 browser console

Comment: seems you were right! since i didn't open the account logs stopped from coming, is there a way I can filter out which logs will come from the access logs?

Comment: Do you mean filter as in stop-from-being-logged or filter as in ignore-some-logs-when-viewing?

Comment: stop logging some actions, I saw online that this is not an option, it's all or nothing, unless I missed something

Comment: I don't believe you can stop logging some messages. Surely if you're logging access, you want to log all accesses? In any case, this is now moving away from a Terraform question - if you want to, you can ask a separate question about configuring AWS S3 logging.